# What's up with the clothes of the "mountain men"?

Tags: the-100

I am wondering about the white "stuff" (see picture) on some of their clothes. I reminds of lines a tailor would draw on clothes. It also looks like they removed the lapels of the suit jacket.

Is there any information on that? Is is style? Is it some kind of dirt?

[image: Dante Wallace]

Comment: That appears to be a denim jacket. As a general rule, when denim gets old or is artificially distressed, the seam lines tend to lighten before the main fabric area. If it seems too even or regular, it's probably been artificially distressed. It's just a normal effect of the fabric, don't read too much into it (DRTMII ?)

Comment: But you can also see white stuff on the tie. I doesn't seem be due to aging.

Comment: Not natural aging, anyway. I call it a wardrobe department that's a little too aggressive with the fabric-distressing treatments. I seriously doubt that there's any in-universe explanation - unless somebody in the Fan-Fic community wants to make one up.

Comment: I have no canon info, but I think Joe L is right; I think it's meant to give the impression that the writers are trying to convey that the Mountain Men are just re-wearing the same clothes over and over for generations, rather than producing anything new.

Comment: I'll agree that it looks like chalk. Someone in Wardrobes probably thought rubbing chalk on the edges would make the fabric look worn, but in reality it just looks bad.

Comment: Well maybe it's supposed to look old and the costumer thought drawing white lines on clothes would achieve that. Otherwise I like the idea of @Liesmith. It could be their way to create some new kind of fashion without making new clothes.

But I agree that unless there is an interview with somebody from the set or an actor and somebody asked that question already we will have to wait for an in-show answer or die not knowing.

Comment: I haven't watched this show, but a very quick google image search suggests that **everyone** in the show is covered in chalk. My guess is that they've got an over-zealous propmaster

Comment: It does mostly apply to seams and folded edges which would wear before and more than other garment areas.

Answer (score 6):

In the show,
it seems that everything mountain men have, beyond food (which they state is from their hydroponic gardens) is very old.

The Mount Weather shelter is shown to have varst warehoused of stuff.
We see mostly the art sections, but I suggest that there is a lot more.

This would also explain the rather unchanged style of the cloths.
If they were making their own, then the fashions would have shifted.
Since they have been just pulling them out of storage,
they are still 20th century fashion.

The white marks are thus likely part of the attempt to make it look aged.
Artificial distressing as discussed in the comments.

I suspect it is suposed to be dust.
You can see the more effective grey dust markes all around it.
It may be that the white marks were suposed to get further treating which got forgotten, or messed up,
ot it may be a plain screw-up:
Eg:
**Costumer**: "I thought this would work, but it didn't"
**Director**: "Well we need to shoot this today, we don't have time or budget to remake these costumes."